# Exclude positionAmt values of dict [jsonArray] object with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I get the following json object with python. I want to exclude the following object whose positionAmt value is greater than 0. How can I do that ?

If the value of positionAmt is zero and greater then delete the row it is on.

```
def webhook(request):
    webhook_received_json = json.loads(request.body)

    while True:
        get_active_position()


def get_active_position():
    print("get_active position")
    sleep(3)

    futures_api_key = "asd"
    futures_secret_key = "fdg"
    client = Client(futures_api_key, futures_secret_key)

    data = client.futures_position_information()
    # data = list
    for key, value in data.items():
        if "positionAmt" >= "0.0000":
            del data[key]
            break
    
    return get_active_position
```

```
[
{'symbol': 'BCHUSDT', 'positionAmt': '0.00000', 'entryPrice': '262.39000'},
,{'symbol': 'BCHUSDT', 'positionAmt': '-0.001', 'entryPrice': '262.39000'},
{'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'positionAmt': '-0.001', 'entryPrice': '386.60000'}]
```

Comment: Show your code and explain what particular problem you are not able to solve. Note that after convert `positionAmt` value to float/Decimal there is no value greater than 0 in sample data (i.e. nothing to exclude).

Comment: hi, added code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value is a string. you need it to convert to `float` or `decimal.Decimal` in order to compare properly. Also you iterate over a list.

```
def get_active_position():
    print("get_active position")
    sleep(3)

    futures_api_key = "asd"
    futures_secret_key = "fdg"
    client = Client(futures_api_key, futures_secret_key)

    data = client.futures_position_information()
    return [item for item in data if float(item.get('positionAmt', '0')) < 0]
```

Note, the code is not tested

EDIT: I edit the code so that it will exclude 0

Comment: yes as i want. but list the ones above positionAmt> = "0.000"

Comment: I don't understand what you want - in your question and in your code you want to delete the items where `positionAmt` is gretaer than 0... In my code I return list with these items excluded.